# grunt-browserify keepAlive and watch options

Tags: gruntjs

When runnning grunt-browserify, there is a flag option for **watch** and another flag option for **keepAlive**. What is the difference between the following two configurations for browserify:

```
example: {
  files: {
    'public/js/bundle.js': 'public/js/main.js'
  },
  options: {
    watch: true,
    keepAlive: true
  }
}
```

AND

```
example: {
  files: {
    'public/js/bundle.js': 'public/js/main.js'
  },
  options: {
    watch: true
  }
}
```

NOTE: The first one has keepAlive set to true and the second one does not.

Answer (score 0):

My `watch` won't actually trigger `watchify` to execute unless `keepAlive` is also true.  Without keepAlive, my browserify will only execute a single time, never passing responsibility to watchify for the bundling process.